# How to Sort Dataset?

Tags: c#

I have Dataset that include table Items, How can I sort this table by Code field ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 23):

With `DataTable`, you usually sort a `DataView` - for example:

```
        DataTable table = dataSet.Tables["foo"];
        DataView view = table.DefaultView;
        view.Sort = "Code";
```

then work with `view`.

Comment: and how can I run any query on this DataSet ?

Answer (score 3):

```
DataSet fileTransferDetail = null; //Data to be sorted.
DataSet result = null; //Declare a dataSet to be filled.

// Sort data
fileTransferDetail.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "ID DESC";
// Store in new Dataset
result.Tables.Add(fileTransferDetail.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a DataView object and call the Sort method on it.  Or, if your dataset came from SQL, use the ORDER BY clause to sort it before it gets loaded into the dataset.

Comment: The `DataView` object has no `Sort` method. It *does* have a `Sort` *property*; although that doesn't explain how to sort the `DataView`.