# Can we arrange the order of the datatables in a dataset?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datatable, dataset

I have DataSet Named as **Album** which contain four DataTables.Name and Order of those tables are

1. Flower
2. Error
3. Photoz
4. Apple

I need to arrange all these DataTables in Dataset(Album) as alphabetical order. Like as follows

1. Apple
2. Error
3. Flower
4. Photoz

I have searched in google but there is no even reltive solution

Comment: Kindly refer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670701/how-to-sort-dataset

Comment: @Aki No that's for Sorting columns inside the data table but what i want is sort list of datatbles in Dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it will take a dataset you pass to it and return a new dataset with the tables ordered appropriately by name.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Function OrderDatatables(ByVal ds As DataSet) As DataSet

    Dim tableList As New SortedList(Of String, DataTable)
    Dim sortedDataset As New DataSet

    For Each table As DataTable In ds.Tables
        tableList.Add(table.TableName, table)
    Next

    For Each tableItem As KeyValuePair(Of String, DataTable) In tableList
        sortedDataset.Tables.Add(tableItem.Value.Clone())
    Next

    Return SortedDataset

End Function
```

**Update**

For adding DataTable Values

```
Function OrderDatatables(ByVal ds As DataSet) As DataSet

    Dim tableList As New SortedList(Of String, DataTable)
    Dim sortedDataset As New DataSet

    For Each table As DataTable In ds.Tables
        tableList.Add(table.TableName, table)
    Next

    For Each tableItem As KeyValuePair(Of String, DataTable) In tableList
        sortedDataset.Tables.Add(ds.Tables(tableItem.Value.Clone().ToString()).Copy())
    Next

    Return SortedDataset

End Function
```

Comment: Hi It's working as expected but it Truncate the DataTable Values. I need datatable value should not remove...